# Matlab OOP code reusing

Tags: matlab, oop

First of all, I belive I should say that I am a newbie on OOP in Matlab, but quite experenced with other languages like C++. So this question may sound like so easy to you but I somehow could not find an explanation to my problem.

Suppose that I have two classes, where the former one is an Abstract class and the latter one is a derived class which is derived from the abstract base class.
You can see an example below.

```
classdef (Abstract) queue < handle 
     properties
        queue_array = [];
        read_index =1;
     end

    methods
       function insert_to_queue (obj, queue_element)
           obj.queue_array = [obj.queue_array, queue_element];
       end

       function clean_queue (obj)
           obj.queue_array = [];
           obj.read_index = 1;
       end
   end   
end




classdef fifo_queue < queue

   properties
   end

   methods
       function get_next_from_queue (obj)
           ...
       end   
   end

end
```

Here as you can see, I put the common functions of all the derived classes to the base class for the purpose of code reuse.

However when I try a scrpt like below

```
 f_que = fifo_queue;

 f_que.instert_to_queue(some_data);  % OK
 f_que.clear_queue();                % Error
```

I got an error like;

```
No appropriate method, property, or field print for class fifo_queue
```

Do you have any idea of why I face with this type of behaviour on MATLAB?
Thanks

Comment: Is it a typo? You named the method `clean_queue` and called `clear_que` in your sample...

Comment: sorry, yeap it is just a typo. I have just fixed it

Comment: I was able to run your code without error (using `clean_queue ` instead of `clear_queue`). If you run it from command line you can use tab to do autocomplete/list available properties and methods

Comment: @mecid, So is your question still active or the problem was only the typo ?

Comment: @Trogdor my problem was not a typo. Honestly I don't have any idea of what caused that kind of error but when I restarted Matlab, the problem has been automatically solved. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: @mecid, did you get any warnings about a member of the class existing and being unable to update changes? it's possible that running `clear all` would have also worked. Regardless, I'm glad you got it working :)

Comment: @Trogdor I don't remember I got that kind of warning. clear all may  be dangereous sometimes, but anyhow I will keep your advice in my mind. Thx :)